# Set a new length for a vector?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I never encountered such action. Can someone explain [this](http://www.peroxide.dk/papers/collision/collision.pdf) on page 47?

The programmer uses a "SetLength" function on a 3-dimensional vector. Here's the statement:

```
VECTOR V = velocity;
V.SetLength(value);
```

What could be the implementation of such function? How is it working?

Comment: This is about vectors represented in some kind of programming language not about mathematics. I think you will get a better answer on  a forum more specific to programming.

Comment: Last time I asked something similar they pointed me to this forum.

Comment: I suppose that while $\vec v$ is a vector, implementation is smth like $\vec v = \frac{\vec v}{|\vec v|}\cdot value$; make vector with length $1$, then make length equal to $value$, and assign to initial vector.

Comment: @Pilpel where was that? I'm pretty sure they shouldn't have sent you here, since you're asking about implementations.

Comment: Thing is, this question lies between this forum and a programming forum. Anyway, @MichaelGaluza that really must be the case, I wanted to be sure since I've never seen such method.

Comment: @Pipel: sorry to hear you've been bounced around. Good luck. The answer mightbe along the lines of Michael Galuza's comment or a coordinate representation could be scaled to change the length. This is a programming issue though, not mathematics.

Comment: @Pilpel, in your paper often used method "normalize" on vector; it's equivalent to V.SetLength(1); so, we are on right way. I think you can implement it in your favourite programming language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made and used such a routine in my own mathematics programming. Here is a mathematical explanation.

A given vector has its own length, which cannot be changed without making it a different vector. However, the vector does define a vector subspace which is all scalar multiples of that vector. You could also say it is the vector subspace for which our original vector is the basis.

That subspace has vectors of all possible lengths, and we may want one with a given desired length. There are two such vectors: one that has the same direction as the original vector and one that has the opposite direction. We probably want the one in the same direction.

We can find that vector by taking our base vector, dividing it by its length, and multiplying that by the new desired length. Here is my 2D implementation, in Object Pascal. "Hypot" returns the length of the vector, which is also the hypotenuse of the right triangle with the given legs.

```
{---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PURPOSE:     Normalize a 2-dimensional vector to have a given length
             (without changing the direction)
EXCEPTIONS:  EZeroDivide  if the vector is the zero vector (zero length)
NOTES:       1. If the "new length" parameter is negative, the resulting
                vector is in the opposite direction to the given vector.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------}
procedure Set2DVecLength(X, Y, NewLen: Extended; var XNew, YNew: Extended);
var
  Factor: Extended;
begin
  Factor := NewLen / Hypot(X, Y);
  XNew := Factor * X;
  YNew := Factor * Y;
end {procedure Set2DVecLength};
```

What is the purpose of such a routine? My first use was in the numerical solution of a system of ordinary differential equations. I simulated one object that was chasing another moving object at a fixed speed. I first got the direction my chaser was to move, then used this routine to change the direction vector to the actual velocity vector for my chaser.